# df.fillna or df.replace not eliminating NaN in my .csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, pycharm

I know there are tons of similar questions here. But none of the answers seem to work for me. Note that I'm a beginner programmer and only learned this through Youtube Tutorials. Note that I'm using a Mac OS and PyCharm

My program downloads [this .csv](https://www.lanuv.nrw.de/fileadmin/lanuv/luft/temes/NO_AM1H.csv) file through this code I found on Youtube

```py
def download_data(csv_url):
    response = request.urlopen(csv_url)
    csv = response.read()
    csv_str = str(csv)
    lines = csv_str.split ("\\n")
    dest_url = r'NO_AM1H.csv'
    fx = open(dest_url,"w")
    for line in lines:
        fx.write (line + "\n")
    fx.close()
```

I then read the .csv and set the delimiter. Lots of the values in the .csv are <7 or empty (NaN). I try to replace them as seen in the picture, however when I print the dataframe (df) it still shows NaN and <7

```py
df = pd.read_csv('NO_AM1H.csv',delimiter=';')
df = df.replace(np.nan,0)
df = df.replace('<7',0)

print(df.tail(4))
```

Any help would be much appreciated and apologize any rookie mistakes. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a moment to read about how to post pandas questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: Where is the [mcve]?

Comment: This isn't directly related to the issue, but how much do you know about that CSV file? I'm writing up a solution, and just noticed that the times go up to `24:00`. How are we supposed to interpret that? Do we consider it to be `00:00`, and increment the associated day by 1?

Answer (score 1):

A quick fix you can do is flag the possible NA values while reading the csv, something like this:

**Method 1:**

```
df = pd.read_csv('NO_AM1H.csv',delimiter=';', na_values=['<7', 'NaN','nan', None])

# then fill the NAs
df = df.fillna(0)
```

**Method 2:**

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x: None if x == '<7' else x)
```

A work around to replace float NAs in pandas is:

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x: 0 if str(x) == 'nan' else x)
```

Comment: Thank you for helping, but it sadly doesn't change the output

Comment: after reading the file, do you still see `<7` in the values ?

Comment: Yes. Sadly it didn't seem to change a thing

Comment: check the edit, I am assuming `"<7"` is being parsed as a string in the df

Comment: It actually changes the <7 to a NaN now but it doesn't fill the NaN with 0

Comment: check the `type`of NA values, they must be float, check the edit.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have an encoding issue.

In linux I used

```
file -i NO_AM1H.csv
```

which told me the file encoding is NO_AM1H.csv: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1

I then import it with read_csv and specify the encoding.

Try this,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('NO_AM1H.csv', sep=';',header=0, encoding='iso-8859-1')

df = df.replace(np.nan,0)
df = df.replace('<7',0)
```

and it looks like,

```
              Datum   Zeit AABU NO AM1H [µg/m³]  ... WALS NO AM1H [µg/m³] WAST NO AM1H [µg/m³] WULA NO AM1H [µg/m³]
8780  18.01.2020  21:00                    0  ...                    0                    0                    0
8781  18.01.2020  22:00                    0  ...                    0                    0                    0
8782  18.01.2020  23:00                    0  ...                    0                    0                    0
8783  18.01.2020  24:00                    0  ...                    0                    0                    0
```

for both .head() and .tail()

note, I did modify your original file and removed the first line (line 0).

update: if you still have empty rows, then try,

```
df=df.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but it still doesn't change anything. Maybe it is noteworthy, that I'm working on a Mac OS using PyCharm

Comment: if these two answers are not working for you then something strange is going on.  You can run your python script from your terminal on a mac.  At this point I'd also check what versions of pandas and numpy you are using.

Comment: also, if it would be helpful, I could upload the new .csv file somewhere for you with no '<7' or empty elements.

Comment: how can I check the versions of Pandas and Numpy I'm using?

Comment: I'm not really sure I just use a text editor.  I used my googler and found https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html.  I'd also check to see if you get similar results from the terminal python script execution.

Answer (score 0):

I copied the content of the file directly from the browser and it works. Remember that the header starts in the second row.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The replace operations aren't working because the DataFrame only contains a single column, with each row containing an entire row from the CSV as a single string. The reason for that is the first line of the file, `#ZEITBEREICH: 18.01.2019 bis 19.01.2020`, which appears to be a comment of some sort, breaks the parsing of the file. We can avoid this issue using a few of the many arguments for `pandas.read_csv()`:

Old:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('NO_AM1H.csv',delimiter=';')
```

New:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('NO_AM1H.csv', delimiter=';', header=0, skiprows=[0])
```

That change alone is enough to fix the parsing, and in turn the replace operations.

---

Next is the matter of the encoding. To quote the docs for urllib.request:

> Note that urlopen returns a bytes object. This is because there is no way for urlopen to automatically determine the encoding of the byte stream it receives from the HTTP server. In general, a program will decode the returned bytes object to string once it determines or guesses the appropriate encoding.

Your code doesn't decode the data properly, which means that, for example the second and third column names become `AABU NO AM1H [\xb5g/m\xb3]` and `BIEL NO AM1H [\xb5g/m\xb3]` respectively. This wouldn't be such a problem if it weren't for the fact that the `.headers.get_content_charset()` method of the response object seemingly fails, returning `None` for this particular file.

---

The `download_data()` function is also needlessly complex. Here is a working solution which is similar in style to your original code:

```py
from urllib import request

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

pd.options.display.width = 0


def download_data():
    csv_url = "https://www.lanuv.nrw.de/fileadmin/lanuv/luft/temes/NO_AM1H.csv"
    response = request.urlopen(csv_url)
    resp_contents = response.read().decode('ISO-8859-1')
    with open('../out/csv_test_out.csv', 'w') as out_file:
        out_file.write(resp_contents)


download_data()

df = pd.read_csv('../out/csv_test_out.csv', delimiter=';', header=0, skiprows=[0])
df = df.replace(np.nan, 0).replace('<7', 0)
```

`df.head()`:

```
        Datum   Zeit  ... WAST NO AM1H [µg/m³] WULA NO AM1H [µg/m³]
0  18.01.2019  01:00  ...                    0                    0
1  18.01.2019  02:00  ...                    0                    0
2  18.01.2019  03:00  ...                    0                    0
3  18.01.2019  04:00  ...                    0                    0
4  18.01.2019  05:00  ...                    0                    0

[5 rows x 59 columns]
```

---

I think we can do much better, though:

```py
import pandas as pd

pd.options.display.width = 0

csv_url = "https://www.lanuv.nrw.de/fileadmin/lanuv/luft/temes/NO_AM1H.csv"

df = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer=csv_url,
                 encoding='ISO-8859-1',
                 header=0,
                 skiprows=[0],
                 comment='#',
                 parse_dates=[[0, 1]],
                 converters={1: lambda val: '23:59' if val == '24:00' else val},
                 na_values=['<7'],
                 delimiter=';')

df.iloc[:, 1:] = df.iloc[:, 1:].fillna(0).astype('Int64')
```

`df.head()`:

```
           Datum_Zeit  ...  WULA NO AM1H [µg/m³]
0 2019-01-18 01:00:00  ...                     0
1 2019-01-18 02:00:00  ...                     0
2 2019-01-18 03:00:00  ...                     0
3 2019-01-18 04:00:00  ...                     0
4 2019-01-18 05:00:00  ...                     0

[5 rows x 58 columns]
```

Comment: I cannot thank you enough. Even though I didn't use all of the code you provided, as I only used chunks of it, my problem is now solved. Great Help!

Comment: @soosenbinder I forgot to mention it in my post; Do you have any questions?